Constraint violation inserting into parent table
I am learning PHP/MySQL and ran into this.  I have combed through Stack Overflow, but did not find anything that helped me solve the issue.
This is running under PHP 7.4.27 / MySQL 8.0.21.
My original question was posted with truncated tables in an effort to shorten the length of the post.  I've updated it with the full table descriptions and added the exact query that I'm using.
I am getting:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`evifs_aqqbo`.`aq_customers`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cust_proj` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `aq_project` (`project_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

when inserting a new record into the aq_project table.
aq_project table:
CREATE TABLE `aq_customers` (
  `customer_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `qb_Customer_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_specific_sales_tax` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_specific_markup` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `export_id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobref` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `jobref_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`,`project_id`,`jobref_code`),
  KEY `indx_custs_cust_addrid` (`customer_address_id`),
  KEY `indx_li_sli` (`project_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cust_proj` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `aq_project` (`project_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_custs_cust_addrid` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_address_id`) REFERENCES `aq_addressrepository` (`address_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

aq_customers table:
CREATE TABLE `aq_project` (
  `project_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobref` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `jobref_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_name` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract_match` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `aq_dealer_rep` int DEFAULT '0',
  `create_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `good_until_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_address_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `freight_sell_override` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `installation_sell_override` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `freight_taxable` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `installation_taxable` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `locksell` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_tax_percent` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_tax_override` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketing_category` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `read_only` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `read_only_description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_protected` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_filter` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `memo` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `opportunity_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `converted_prices_currency_symbol` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `converted_sell_price` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `converted_prices_currency_exchange_rate` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_column_3_name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_column_1_name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_column_2_name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_db_modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `warehouse` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `duplicated_projects` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `install_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `isService` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `track_proj` enum('Yes','No') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `do_not_track_proj` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `qbo_customer_status` enum('true','false') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dealer_rep_address_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_coordinator_address_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dealer_rep` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`,`jobref_code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `INDX_jobref_code` (`jobref_code`),
  KEY `indx_proj_jobref` (`jobref`),
  KEY `indx_proj_project_addrid` (`project_address_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

The query that is throwing the error is:
INSERT INTO aq_project (`code`,`create_date`,`password_protected`,`read_only_description`
 ,`read_only`,`sales_tax_percent`,`installation_taxable`,`freight_taxable`
 ,`freight_sell_override`,`project_address_id`,`good_until_date`,`bid_date`
 ,`modified_date`,`project_name`,`jobref`,`project_id`
 ,`status`,`locksell`,`custom_column_1_name`,`track_proj`
 ,`jobref_code`,`dealer_rep`,`dealer_rep_address_id`,`class_id`
,`project_coordinator_address_id`
) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) as NEW
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `code` = new.`code`, `create_date` = new.`create_date`
, `password_protected` = new.`password_protected`
, `read_only_description` = new.`read_only_description`
, `read_only` = new.`read_only`
, `sales_tax_percent` = new.`sales_tax_percent`
, `installation_taxable` = new.`installation_taxable`
, `freight_taxable` = new.`freight_taxable`
, `freight_sell_override` = new.`freight_sell_override`
, `project_address_id` = new.`project_address_id`
, `good_until_date` = new.`good_until_date`
, `bid_date` = new.`bid_date`
, `modified_date` = new.`modified_date`
, `project_name` = new.`project_name`
, `jobref` = new.`jobref`
, `project_id` = new.`project_id`
, `status` = new.`status`
, `locksell` = new.`locksell`
, `custom_column_1_name` = new.`custom_column_1_name`
, `track_proj` = new.`track_proj`
, `jobref_code` = new.`jobref_code`
, `dealer_rep` = new.`dealer_rep`
, `dealer_rep_address_id` = new.`dealer_rep_address_id`
, `class_id` = new.`class_id`
, `project_coordinator_address_id` = new.`project_coordinator_address_id`
;

where
$values = array (
      0 => 'CONTRACT',
      1 => '2024-12-10',
      2 => 'true',
      3 => 'Not Read Only',
      4 => '0',
      5 => '7',
      6 => 'true',
      7 => 'true',
      8 => '1200',
      9 => '15e149c4-0f04-49e1-8761-d70ede7332f6',
      10 => '2025-01-09T12:27:54.6841706',
      11 => '2024-12-10T12:27:54.6841706',
      12 => '2024-12-11',
      13 => '242011 Tom\'s Sub Shop Charles Town, WV',
      14 => '242011',
      15 => '3f7265f4-57b3-40d5-b4dd-ceaad93ae4a6',
      16 => 'Active',
      17 => '',
      18 => 'Water AFF',
      19 => 'Yes',
      20 => '242011_CONTRACT',
      21 => 'Long L',
      22 => 'b159136f-e9a7-4e15-8781-7a92929ddb03',
      23 => '4100000000000368102',
      24 => 'e0c456ff-655c-4c9a-99a3-3f567ed2b16f',
    )

with the project_id being element 15 in the array: '3f7265f4-57b3-40d5-b4dd-ceaad93ae4a6`
aq_customers references aq_project, so I don't understand why I can't insert the record in the parent table without throwing this violation.  The fk in aq_customers is used to cascade deletion of the project records from aq_customers when a project is deleted from aq_project.
From SQLyog:


It should not fail, check triggers and provide example to prove your assertation.

No problems: https://dbfiddle.uk/Y1f99MKS

I can't insert - show your insert query.

This error can only happen when inserting into aq_customers, not when inserting into aq_project. So it must be coming from a different query than the one you think.

I tried testing your tables on my local MySQL 8.4.3 instance. I found at least two errors: (1) the aq_customers table has an extra comma near the end, so creating the table fails. (2) The foreign key in aq_customers is a single column, but the primary key of aq_project is two columns. This results in an error in my version of MySQL. So I conclude that the tables you are having trouble with are substantially different from the ones you show above, and that makes me doubt that the error you reported is accurate as well.

PHP is irrelevant to this question. What might matter is the version of MySQL.

Have you checked for triggers as the first comment suggests? That's usually the reason for impossible errors like this.

MySQL 8.0.21 - updated the post to include this info.  TY.

@P.Salmon - the db has two triggers which are not triggered by activity in either of these tables.

I have little model for this issue. INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE you update existing project_id to another project_id1->project_id2. This violate reference from aq_customers  with reference to project_id1.  See example(https://dbfiddle.uk/Qhclr1W_). Possible conflict keys for ON DUPLICATE is  KEY indx_proj_jobref (jobref). In my mode I use 'jobref1'.

@ValNik - your comment put me on the right track!  Thank you!

I would like to give my example as an answer to the question. Is it possible to open a question for answers?(dbfiddle.uk/Qhclr1W_)

I will give a simplified model of the situation where the error shown by OP occurs.
Two tables have a constraint when a link from the aq_Customers table through the Project_id column requires a row with such a Project_id in the aq_Project table.
If you try to update a row in the Projects table so that the link from Customers becomes invalid, the specified error will occur.
1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
See example
CREATE TABLE `aq_project` (
  `project_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Test') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobref` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `jobref_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_name` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`,`jobref_code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `INDX_jobref_code` (`jobref_code`),
  KEY `indx_proj_jobref` (`jobref`),  -- this key for ON DUPLICATE
  KEY `indx_proj_project_addrid` (`project_address_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `aq_customers` (
  `customer_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `jobref_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`,`project_id`,`jobref_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cust_proj` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `aq_project` (`project_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO aq_project VALUES 
('project_id1','Active','jobref1','code1','jobref code1','project name1');
 
INSERT INTO aq_project VALUES 
('project_id1','Active','jobref1','code1','jobref code2','project name1');




project_id
status
jobref
code
jobref_code
project_name




project_id1
Active
jobref1
code1
jobref code1
project name1


project_id1
Active
jobref1
code1
jobref code2
project name1



INSERT INTO aq_customers VALUES 
('customer_id1', null,'address_id1','project_id1','jobref code1')
;




customer_id
parent_id
customer_address_id
project_id
jobref_code




customer_id1
null
address_id1
project_id1
jobref code1



Above DML operations is successful.
Next query violate constraint with update project_id= new.Project_id
INSERT INTO aq_project VALUES 
('project_id2','Active','jobref1','code1','jobref code2','project name1') as new
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `status` = 'Test',`project_id`= new.Project_id
;


Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fiddle`.`aq_customers`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cust_proj` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `aq_project` (`project_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)


ON DUPLICATE event arrises for key jobref.    KEY indx_proj_jobref (jobref),
Then we try update project_id, which causes an error in the parent table. With this update row in aq_customers do not have reference to aq_project.
I think it was the occurrence of an error in the parent table that caused the misunderstanding of the OP.
fiddle
